# Python, Sorting averages

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I have half a problem with sorting data from a text file. I am suppose to find the average from 3 numbers which are weighted and print out which name within the text file that particular average belongs to.

I have managed to do this for the highest average but I have had a few problems finding the lowest average.

Sample text from the file.

```
Shoes 210 130 67
Bags  167 321 459
```

Position 0 in the text file is the name of the department. Position 1 in the file is 'Good Votes'. Position 2 'Fair Votes'. Position 3 'Poor Votes'.

The highest average in the list is Shoes with an average of 2.351 and the lowest average in the list is Bags with an average of 1.692.

I have defined a function to calculate the average and have called it without any problems for the highest average.

```
highestAverage = 0
    highestAvgDepName = 0      
    if choice2 == 1:
        calculateAverage(allDepartments,choice2)
        for x in range (10):
            if highestAverage < calculateAverage(allDepartments, x):
                highestAverage = calculateAverage(allDepartments, x)
                highestAvgDepName = x
```

The only issue I have is getting this to find the lowest average. I have tried creating a new function that calculates the average and multiplies it by -1 turning all the numbers negative, which should technically make the largest number -1.692 but it throws me 55.***.

I have looked into bubble sorting, however, I don't understand how to do that from a text file.

```
def calculateAverage(allDepartments, choice2):
total = allDepartments[choice2][1] + allDepartments[choice2][2] + allDepartments[choice2][3]
return((allDepartments[choice2][1]*3 + allDepartments[choice2][2]*2 + allDepartments[choice2][3])/total)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this :

```
highestAverage = 0
highestAvgDepName = 0      
if choice2 == 1:
    calculateAverage(allDepartments,choice2)
    for x in range (10):
        if highestAverage > calculateAverage(allDepartments, x):
            highestAverage = calculateAverage(allDepartments, x)
            highestAvgDepName = x
```

Comment: I tried inverting the operator but it gives me the wrong department with an average of 0.000

Comment: @s.kelly can you post it in your question where it is readable?

Comment: Can you please provide information about your parsing code also ? I think, there's also an issue over there.

Answer (score 0):

You could store your departments in a dictionary keyed on average and then store your averages in a list and sort the list to get the highest and lowest average like so

```
def calculateAverage(choice2):
    total = choice2[0] + choice2[1] + choice2[2]
    return((choice2[0]*3 + choice2[1]*2 + choice2[2])/total)

d={}
l = []
with open(file,'r') as f:
    for i in f:
        tmp = i.split()
        avg = calculateAverage([float(j) for j in tmp[1:]])
        d[avg] = tmp[0]
        l.append(avg)
    l = sorted(l)
print 'Highest: {} {:.4}'.format(d[highest], highest)
print 'Lowest: {} {:.4}'.format(d[lowest], lowest)

Highest: Shoes 2.351
Lowest: Bags 1.692
```

or you can do it this way which uses less memory

```
def calculateAverage(choice2):
    total = choice2[0] + choice2[1] + choice2[2]
    return((choice2[0]*3 + choice2[1]*2 + choice2[2])/total)
d={}
l = []
highest = -100000
lowest = 100000

with open(file,'r') as f:
    for i in f:
        tmp = i.split()
        avg = calculateAverage([float(j) for j in tmp[1:]])
        d[avg] = tmp[0]
        if avg > highest:
            highest = avg
        if avg < lowest:
            lowest = avg
print 'Highest: {} {:.4}'.format(d[highest], highest)
print 'Lowest: {} {:.4}'.format(d[lowest], lowest)
```

Comment: Thank you! I haven't learnt dictionaries in such detail yet but it works. Would there be a way to, when printing the statements, change highest and lowest to 3sf? (i.e. 2.351)

Comment: @s.kelly Yes, you can use format to print the string with constraints. Here is a [link](https://pyformat.info/) so you can read more on it. It is very useful when printing complicated strings.